# Upper bound the Polylogarithm $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds, polylogarithm

Let $x \in (0,1)$ be some real number, we can then consider the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm):
$$\operatorname{L}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$
It is not hard to see that the following upper bound holds:
$$
\operatorname{L}_2(x) = x \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2} \leq x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{x\pi^2}{6}.
$$
One could continue to get a finer upper bound using the same strategy:
$$
\operatorname{L}_2(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{x^n}{n^2} + \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2}
$$
where we can then upper bound $$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2} \leq x^{m+1} \cdot \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
I am quite pleased with this, but was wondering if there are alternative, better well known bounds.

Comment: Just to be precise it is more common to call this special Polylogarithm ["Dilogarithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) $($or Spence's Function$)$ denoted as $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$.

Comment: You can use this formula : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} = (1-x) \log(1-x) + x$. But I don't know if it will be better

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for! You can post it as an answer if you want to. Just a small thing: your last $x$ should be a $1$ I believe, i.e. $(1-x) \log(1-x) + 1$.